# Can't reuse file across Steps with GitHub Actions

Tags: maven, github, continuous-deployment, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to copy a jar via SCP in a GitHub Action which I build with maven in the step before.
My problem is, that the SCP step never finds the jar file and fails. Any idea how I can fix/realize this, so the step finds the file?

This is the error I get:
Error: localFile does not exist at /home/runner/work/rest-api/rest-api/target/RestApi.jar

This is what my workflow looks like:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        run: |
          mvn clean package
      - name: Deployment
        uses: garygrossgarten/github-action-scp@release
        with:
          local: "/home/runner/work/rest-api/rest-api/target/RestApi.jar"
          remote: "/opt/rest-api/"
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
```

Thanks in Advance
Ael

Comment: Please add the log output / error message to your question

Comment: You need to make sure that your local path is correct and the file also exists. You can do that by runing `ls` and `pwd`. As @riQQ said, it would be great if you could post the log error.